# Check a check box if it's value is in DB. PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a loop of checkboxes from a MySql table "exercise" in a form as shown below:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="insertDrills.php">

  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <?php do { ?>
      <tr>
        <td>


<input type="checkbox" name="drillSelect[]" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['drillID']; ?>" id="drillSelect" />

        <?php echo $row_Recordset1['rubrik']; ?>


        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">



      <input name="spelarID" type="hidden" id="spelarID" value="<?php echo $row_rsSpelare['id']; ?>" />
      <input name="date" type="hidden" id="date" value="<? print date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Välj övningar" />
  <input type="button" value="Avbryt" onclick="window.close();"></button>



      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

The value from the hidden fied "spelarID" along with the value from the checkbox array are inserted to a look-up table "exercise_spelare_ref" with this:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['spelarID']; 
$drills = $_POST['drillSelect'];
$date = $_POST['date']; 

$inserts = array(); 
foreach ($drills as $drills)
    $inserts[] = "('$id','$drills','','$date')"; 


$query = "REPLACE INTO exercise_spelare_ref VALUES ". implode(", ", $inserts);

//echo "query = $query"; // for debugging purposes, remove this once it is working 
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
```

How can I make values that are in the look-up table marked as "checked" in the form?

There are a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4069477 written by Martin Bean but I cant get it to work?

I have been stuck here for ever, hope anyone can help me out here!

I tried Martin Beans script like:

```
$uid = $row_rsSpelare['id']; // your logged in user's ID

$exercise = array();

// get an array of exercise
$sql = "SELECT drillID FROM exercise";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    $exercise[$row->id] = $row->drillID;
}

// get an array of exercise user has checked
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT drillID FROM exercise_spelare_ref WHERE id = '$uid'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    $checked[] = $row->drillID;
}

// this would be templated in a real world situation
foreach ($exercise as $id => $drillID) {
    $checked = "";
    // check box if user has selected this exercise
    if (in_array($checked, $id)) {
        $checked = 'checked="checked" ';
    }
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="drillSelect[]" value="'.$id.'" '.$checked.'/>';
}
```

But getting a warning:

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /customers/b/d/e/teeview.se/httpd.www/analys_kund/selectDrills.php on line 158

Line 158 is:

```
 if (in_array($checked, $id)) {
```

Comment: **SQL injection... SQL injection everywhere!** Besides that: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Ok ThiefMaster, I plan to take care of SQL injections once script is working as supposed. This is just a little bit of a comprehensive site all written with mysql so I thought it might be easy to continue like the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you will need to `SELECT` the items from the table, store them into an array, and if the current checkbox's ID matches something in the array, add the `checked` attribute to it in the HTML.

Comment: Well ok. normaly I use to do that with this:<input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_Recordset1['id'],$spelare))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> But I fail when make an array out of the look-up table values.